# Facial recognition iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, face-recognition

I have to build an app to recognize person on photo and find if this person is stored in phone book. I made face detection, I know how to take photos from people stored in phone book but I stuck on recognizing if the person is the same..

I want to ask what would be the easiest way to do it - i saw that iOS 10 comes with facial recognition in Photos app - is there any API to use facial recognition in iOS 10?

or should I use Open CV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built something similar some years ago.
I would suggest you look into [perceptual hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) as it's an easy and inexpensive way of matching images.

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer. I imagine you already found it, but if not, have a look at [cocoaimagehashing](https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing)

Answer (score 2):

Face detection can be performed natively, as you've already found out, but to identify the faces you'll have to use something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) as there's no API available to do this presently

There's some information about how OpenCV can be used to recognise faces [here.](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html)

Information about how to use it with Xcode [here.](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/)

Answer (score 0):

[You can have a look at the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html), but this way your app will work only on iOS 10 and future versions.

If you plan to support older iOS versions or make also an Android app go for OpenCV

Comment: This won't match the persons face to the address book, this will just detect faces in an image? They said they've already achieved that.